# How do you use Snowflake RATIO_TO_REPORT to be precise?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having a problem with Snowflake function RATIO_TO_REPORT and it's rounding. It seems like there is default rounding behavior, which causes a sum to be different from 1.

How would you address this issue?

[RATIO_TO_REPORT Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnxGv.png)

Cheers,

Joe

Comment: This might be worth a support ticket to Snowflake, so they can look into it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing going on here is technically "wrong" - as you've identified, this is a rounding issue. Each of the RATIO_TO_REPORT results is correct, and the sum of the values is *also* correct.

The best way to get around this is to force RATIO_TO_REPORT to output a more precise number by casting the input to `NUMBER` rather than `INTEGER`. In my testing, the below worked well:

```
-- Create the table for testing
CREATE TABLE R2R_TEST (activity_count integer);

-- Insert the values from the example screenshot.
INSERT INTO R2R_TEST VALUES (210),(11754),(3660),(66);

-- Create the test RATIO_TO_REPORT query with the cast to NUMBER
SELECT RATIO_TO_REPORT(activity_count::number(32,8))  OVER (ORDER BY activity_count) r2r FROM R2R_TEST;

-- Check our work.
with test as (SELECT RATIO_TO_REPORT(activity_count::number(32,8))  OVER (ORDER BY activity_count) r2r FROM R2R_TEST)
SELECT SUM(r2r) FROM test; -- 1.0000000000[...]
```

You can see that all I've done is cast `activity_count` to a `NUMBER`, and this gives the unrounded result.